# Outlook web add-in for iOS not persisting 3rd party cookies - works in Safari

Tags: outlook-web-addins

I am developing an app for our company; because of legacy reasons when the user logs in we use a 
third party JSESSIONID cookie.

**Issue**

What I am seeing is that the cookie when sent to the client is not saved, and therefore not sent on subsequent requests to the server.  As such, the server does not think the user is logged in.

Normally I would attribute this to the blocking of 3rd party cookies feature of WebKit/View, but I have turned this off in the Safari settings.

*As an FYI we have an Ionic/Cordova project that is based on the same code and it works fine in iOS.*

- If I use the Add-in on MacOS (Native Outlook and Outlook Web) it works fine.
- Works fine in Chrome/Firefox as well.
- Works in Android on Outlook for Android app

Our server sets all the correct CORS headers as well.

Since the add-in is just a webapp, I can launch it directly in Safari on iOS, and login there; this also works.

I am aware that Apple regressed WebKit in version 12 (CORS related), but they fixed it in the latest version of iOS 13/MacOS.  However, Outlook for iOS (WebView) does not appear to be saving cookies.  I can see that looking at the requests coming to the server, they are missing the SessionID which was sent to the client.

I can also see it from the requests when I run through a proxy (Charles) that the Cookie header is not set.

It is also almost impossible to debug the WebView in Outlook for iOS (the webview does not show up in the Safari Developer menu on my Mac).  I am easily able to debug other WebViews such as the mobile project mentioned above.

**Question**

Is the Webview configured to prevent 3rd party cookies explicitly? if yes, can it be turned off somehow? I have turned off the 3rd party tracking in Safari, but that does not appear to help.

I have been reluctant to use the DialogJS API since the login flow is working on my Mac; and this would considerable change our UX for login.  Also, I have not seen any examples of using this API for a mobile project.  Can it be used with a mobile project, and if so what would it look like?

All the examples relate to the desktop only.

Comment: Hi, we're trying to get to the root of this issue. Could you run this code in your add-in and check if cookies are retained on the client side?

`document.cookie = "Something";
console.log(document.cookie);`

Comment: Could you also check if they're retained across sessions?

Comment: I added the code you suggested.  I can only reproduce this on an iOS device, I can't debug through Safari.

I can confirm that the cookie created is retained across sessions (but not if Outlook is restarted)

I see the new cookie plus 2 other cookies (both Microsoft cookies).

I see the JSESSIONID cookie being sent.

It is not httpOnly, and does not appear in the list of cookies written to the console.

Comment: Using a proxy, I can confirm that none of the cookies are being sent on the next request (not the one I set, and not my JSESSIONID cookie).

I can't tell if the JSESSIONID cookie was actually saved by the WebView.

Comment: The answer to your question on Dialog JS API is yes, display dialog is supported on IOS  as well. You can use it the same way as for other clients. Are the cookies sent for any other add-in in your device?

Comment: I did try Dialog JS API, and unfortunately I encountered the same problem, since we do Cookie based authentication, and the cookie isn't being sent with every request after login. The only other add-in I have is for OneNote, and it appears to only use Cookies to provide the bearer token; which it then uses the token to authenticate.  I am working on an example (app & server) to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Hi.  I created some sample code that replicates the issue I have seen.  I have posted the code in GitHub.  You can clone it here https://github.com/robwatt/cookieAuthProject.  The project includes a server, add-in, and a couple other bits.

Comment: Could you please share the hosted endpoint for your Add-in and also a manifest file for hitting the same?

Comment: Manifest file: https://cookieaddin.z13.web.core.windows.net/manifest.xml.
Hosted endpoint: https://cookieauth2.azurewebsites.net/.  It shuts down if it hasn't been accessed in awhile, so give it time to spin up.

Comment: FYI: usernames are listed in the github repo.

Comment: We downloaded manifest and installed the add-in, but on opening up add-in it's asking for credentials. We found 2 usernames that are present in the project's DB, but we weren't able find the password. Can you please share any test credentials for repro?

Comment: Sorry! I thought I had documented that.  The password is...password for both accounts.

Comment: Credentials shared are not working for us. Can you please try again and if there are any changes in credentials, please share it with us.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay.  I retested; and one thing I noticed the email address is case sensitive.  For now, please make sure all characters are lower-case.  Test@test.com is NOT the same as test@test.com.  I will update the code.

Comment: Site updated, case doesn't matter anymore.  If credentials are correct, a success should show "Status: you hit the authentication endpoint", otherwise you should see "You go the home page" - this general means the cookie isn't sent to the server.  Cookie is configured as "secure; sameSite=none".

Comment: I'm running into a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61924058/images-in-emails-are-inconsistently-being-cached-in-ios-outlook-app) with the Outlook iOS app (not necessarily using a web add-in). It's not allowing any of my cookies to be set. @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT do you know if all cookies are allowed/passed along by the Outlook iOS app? It may not be the addin related code, it may just be that the iOS app isn't whitelisting it (like in [here](https://medium.com/@mahithegeek/cookies-in-ios-nshttpcookie-and-nshttpcookiestorage-696564bc6975))